# How to estimate mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution from noisy data?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, estimation, white-noise, errors-in-variables

I have $n$ observations, $x_i$ following a normal distribution. I would like to estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from my samples. Normally I would simply 
estimate

$\mu=(\sum x_i)/n$ and
$\sigma^2=\sum (x_i-\mu)^2/(n-1)$.

However I know that my samples $x_i$ are noisy.
I know that  the 95% confidence interval of

$x_i$ is $[x_i-t, x_i+t]$

with the same $t$ for all $x_i$. How do I take the noise into account when estimating $\sigma$?

If I don’t take the confidence interval into account the estimation of $\sigma$ might be too large.

Comment: What is a confidence interval for $x_i$? The $x_i$ are **data**, immutable and unchangeable as far as you are concerned; you can have 100% confidence that the value of $x_i$ is **exactly** $x_i$, no more, no less.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for helping me to state  my question more precisely. 
The x_i are estimations an unknown value X_i. I can measure X_i with a certain device. The device makes a certain error. I assume that the measurements are normally distributed.  
I have (unfortunately) only  two measurements v_1 and v_2 with the device to determine X_i. So I estimate X_i\app x_i=(v_1+v_2)/2. So I know that X_i\in [x_i-t, x_i+t] with a probability of 95% with the usual t for confidence intervals. Since I have only 2 measurements my confidence interval will be large.

Comment: Please edit the information into your question.

Comment: Is this not the prototypical ANOVA (components of variance) problem? Do you have two replicate measurement for *each* $x$ ("balanced" data) or have you replicated only one of them ("unbalanced" data)?

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:
Is this not the prototypical ANOVA (components of variance) problem? Do you have two replicate measurement for each x ("balanced" data) or have you replicated only one of them ("unbalanced" data)? – whuber

Since the OP didn't respond to the implicit questions by whuber, but I can show (with simulated data) how this could be done in `R` when there are replicate measurements for each $X_i$:

```
library(lme4)

set.seed(7*11*13) # my public seed 
X <- 1:10
r <- 3 
mu <- rep(X,rep(3,length(X)))
obs <- rnorm(length(mu),mu,1)

ind <- as.factor(mu)
mydata <- data.frame(obs, mu, ind)
mod <- lmer(obs ~ 1 + ind + (1 | ind), data=mydata )

 mod
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: obs ~ 1 + ind + (1 | ind)
   Data: mydata
REML criterion at convergence: 74.71
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 ind      (Intercept) 3.14    
 Residual             1.19    
Number of obs: 30, groups:  ind, 10
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)         ind2         ind3         ind4         ind5         ind6  
     1.6086      -0.6777       1.2451       2.5058       3.8129       4.7079  
       ind7         ind8         ind9        ind10  
     5.1083       7.2207       6.7395       7.7469
```

If you really know the true values for your specimens (as measured by some much more precise instrument, say) you can do:

```
 mod2 <- lmer(obs ~ 0 + offset(mu) + (1 | ind), data=mydata )
 mod2
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: obs ~ 0 + offset(mu) + (1 | ind)
   Data: mydata
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 96.7257  99.5281 -46.3629  92.7257       28 
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 ind      (Intercept) 0.000   
 Residual             1.135   
Number of obs: 30, groups:  ind, 10
No fixed effect coefficients
```